# How to terminate a SCNTransaction ongoing?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scntranscaction

I use SCNTransaction to move game objects. More specifically, when the player taps somewhere on the screen, the object will move towards that destination. But sometimes the player may make a wrong move, so I want to create a button which can terminate all SCNTransactions.

However, unlike SKAction, which can be terminated with a simple line - self.removeAllActions(), SCNTransaction cannot be terminated or even paused from the outside according to the Apple Developer Documentation. Even worse, I find that before the object reaches its destination, its position has already changed to the destination's position, so I cannot simply use another SCNTransaction to counteract the ongoing one after knowing the object's current position.

Can anybody give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNTransaction` and its animation principles follow the one of Core Animation and `CATransaction`. To stop an animation you will have to set the model value to the current presentation value. For instance:

```
node.position = node.presentation.position
```

But if you are familiar with `SKAction` and would like to implement the same logic in your SceneKit app, you might want to have a look at [`SCNAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction). They work identically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe using the SCNAction is a better solution here. I'll try it.